# Is there a way to create a hierarchy of columns from a delimiter in the column names in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with over 500 columns and they look like they were originally in a hierarchy that has been flattened and their new titles have been concatenated with underscores (see below example).

Is there a way to pull out each of the levels and re-create the hierarchy?

**This is an example of some of the columns in the dataset:**
['CEO_FEM_CAS', 'CEO_FEM_FTCONT', 'CEO_FEM_FTPERM', 'CEO_FEM_PTCONT', 'CEO_FEM_PTPERM', 'CEO_MAL_CAS', 'CEO_MAL_FTCONT', 'CEO_MAL_FTPERM', 'CEO_MAL_PTCONT', 'CEO_MAL_PTPERM', 'KMP_FEM_CAS', 'KMP_FEM_FTCONT', 'KMP_FEM_FTPERM', 'KMP_FEM_PTCONT', 'KMP_FEM_PTPERM', 'KMP_MAL_CAS', 'KMP_MAL_FTCONT', 'KMP_MAL_FTPERM', 'KMP_MAL_PTCONT', 'KMP_MAL_PTPERM']

**The hierarchy from this that I want to get is:**
[Desired Hierarchy of Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY4qe.png)

**Explanation:** CEO and KMP are level 0, FEM and MAL are level 1, CAS, FTCONTRACT, FTPERM, PTCONT, PTPERM are level 2

I would like to be able to achieve this in Pandas in Python, but I'm also open to R if there is an easy way to do it.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [multiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays) in pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = [
    'CEO_FEM_CAS', 'CEO_FEM_FTCONT', 'CEO_FEM_FTPERM', 'CEO_FEM_PTCONT', 
    'CEO_FEM_PTPERM', 'CEO_MAL_CAS', 'CEO_MAL_FTCONT', 'CEO_MAL_FTPERM', 
    'CEO_MAL_PTCONT', 'CEO_MAL_PTPERM', 'KMP_FEM_CAS', 'KMP_FEM_FTCONT', 
    'KMP_FEM_FTPERM', 'KMP_FEM_PTCONT', 'KMP_FEM_PTPERM', 'KMP_MAL_CAS', 
    'KMP_MAL_FTCONT', 'KMP_MAL_FTPERM', 'KMP_MAL_PTCONT', 'KMP_MAL_PTPERM',]

first_part = []
second_part = []
third_part = []

for column_name in column_names:
    split_column_name = column.split('_')
    first_part.append(split_column_name[0])
    second_part.append(split_column_name[1])
    third_part.append(split_column_name[2])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[first_part, second_part, third_part])
```